# Drupal 8 custom menu item different URI

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

In Drupal 8 I have a multi language menu. I'm able to translate the title, but how can I point to a URI specific for that language?

When I change it in one language (e.g. http://www.example.com), it is also changed in the other language, where I want a different domain (e.g. http://www.example.nl).

Is it really necessary to build a menu per language to work around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, without contrib modules you need a [separate menu](http://www.drupal8multilingual.org/features-used-hacks/menu-language).

However, there is a module for this: [translatable_menu_link_uri](https://www.drupal.org/project/translatable_menu_link_uri).